# How big could a cannon be made

Tags: science-based, weapons

what is the absolute upper bound on the size of gunpowder cannons, (not rail guns or similar) in terms of shell weight and bore diameter before some mechanical or material problem prevents it from being usable?

Assumptions:

1. Assume today's technology.
2. The projectile should be a metal ball
3. The gunpowder should be fed loose, not in a cartridge.
4. The cannon should be able to be used more than once without destroying itself.
5. The cannon should have a range greater than 2km

I'm specifically looking for the limit of the materials that contain the explosion.

For example: The metals will crack if more than "X" kg of gunpowder explodes inside, or the firing mechanism will be too damaged in the explosion for the cannon to be reused.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! - What technology level are we talking? Are these old-fashioned fuse-lit cannons? Are they made by casting or boring? Are they made from iron or steel?  Would a Big Bertha be an acceptable answer? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bertha_(howitzer)

Comment: What do you mean by mechanical problem? Like getting the Shell into the cannon? moving the cannon? or damage to the cannon when firing it?

Comment: Iron? Or any metal? Or any known substance?

Comment: More information would be useful to make better answer. Use and type of the cannon? Some information on technology and your world in general. Without that it is more reference to our worlds cannons and their history with some limitations in their use.

Comment: There is a [list of the largest cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_largest_cannon_by_caliber) on Wikipedia, organized by the kind of cannon (stone ball, iron ball and shot, explosive shell).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  I'm putting this question on hold temporarily so that you can address the questions you've received before people start guessing.  Please [edit] your question to answer the questions about technology level, materials, construction, etc.  After you edit, the community will review and can reopen your question. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexP I always want to say that Schwerer Gustav would the largest.  40Km range, 7 tonne shells, 500 men crew, 30-45 minutes a shot and actually used in in WWII.

Comment: The cost and awkwardness goes up a lot faster than the boom, there's a point where nobody is going to bother but there's no maximum size.  (There is a maximum velocity, though--the shell always is thrown slower than the burn speed of the propellant.)

Comment: The Krupp K5 railway cannon was capable of firing normal shells 30km, and a special version which was bored out to fire the Peenemünde Arrow Shell an astounding 100km. Gerald Bull was a Canadian artillery scientist who hoped to put a shell into orbit, and HARP test guns were throwing shells to a maximum altitude of 180km. Sadly, he started working for unsavoury charters and was assassinated.

Comment: The short answer is that there is no such limit. There are hard engineering limits to maximum chamber pressure for a given tech level; and there is a limit to the longest effective barrel length. (The latter limit applies to a conventional, single chambered gun -- the reason the German V3 had many chambers.) But the only limits to calibre and shell weight are practical issues to do with "how the heck do we build it?" and "is it worth the trouble?" BTW, how you load the powder is not relevant to the question; and 2 km is extremely short range for a large gun with modern tech.